# Commons-lang-2.6.jar and FilteringClassLoader Issue

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, weblogic11g, apache-commons-lang

This is in continuation of [Despite having commons-lang included in pom, getting exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28186267/599528) I have the following in weblogic-application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>commons-lang.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

However I am still getting

```
Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join
(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

How come classloader filtering is not able to detect jar mentioned in

```
weblogic-application.xml
```

Comment: _<package-name>commons-lang.*</package-name>_ doesn't look like a *package* name. _org.apache.commons.lang_ will probably suit better.

Comment: Tome is correct, specifically `<package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<package-name>commons-lang.*</package-name>` does not look valid. `commons-lang` is the artifact ID of the library, not a valid package.

Replace this by something like `<package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>` or `<package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>` and it should world correctly.